# Authenticating from PHP to Java and retrieve data via WSDL

Tags: java, php, authentication, wsdl, single-sign-on

Ok, so I inherited a project where our core program is built by another company (built in Java) and I have to build another program around it. Problem is that the Java program has to stay as is and I am only allowed to authenticate through to it and pull the findings once users go through there. I am not even sure what to ask for cause I've never cross authenticated before nor used a WSDL etc...

I am an intermediate/advanced PHP coder and would have rather built the entire thing from the ground up (it would be faster and customizable) but, i can't. this java application needs to stand on its own--maybe in an iFrame--and once our users sign into our site, they need to automatically signed in there so when they click on it from the panel, they perform their actions which mark them complete there. We read their completion and mark them complete on our side (via PHP). Their develops have a WSDL file that supposedly we pass the information and we can read their completion and status stuff. No idea how to use it.

The dev environment is IIS 7 (im more used to linux and unix environments)

Any idea where I should start? How to do this? What questions I should ask their developer for so I can develop the PHP side of things?

Comment: http://php.net/book.soap - And you can ask them to provide you a PHP SDK for their WSDL so that you get actually working example code if for you this is actually totally new. - http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/